# Add Poisson Noise with a Given SNR in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

I am writing a MATLAB code where I want to add Poisson noise to images to see how well my algorithm performs. I want to test the code with a given signal to noise ratios (SNR). However, how do I add Poisson noise in order to obtain the same SNR? I have tested `imnoise` with MATLAB, but with a certain constant chosen, the SNR changes for image for image.

For the record, I have added noise on an image `I` using

```
Noisyimage = Constant*imnoise(I/constant, 'Poisson')
```

I measure the SNR as

```
signanoiseratio = snr(I, Noisyimage-I)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to read carefully the documentation of [`imnoise()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html):

> J = imnoise(I,'poisson') generates Poisson noise from the data instead of adding artificial noise to the data. If I is double precision, then input pixel values are interpreted as means of Poisson distributions scaled up by 1e12. For example, if an input pixel has the value 5.5e-12, then the corresponding output pixel will be generated from a Poisson distribution with mean of 5.5 and then scaled back down by 1e12. If I is single precision, the scale factor used is 1e6. If I is uint8 or uint16, then input pixel values are used directly without scaling. For example, if a pixel in a uint8 input has the value 10, then the corresponding output pixel will be generated from a Poisson distribution with mean 10.

Namely the noise isn't added, it is a function of data.

To get what you want you need to use [Poisson Random Number Generator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/poissrnd.html) and use it to generate noise to be added to the image (Remembering the connection between the variance and $ $ parameter of the [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) which means they are equal).